# Convert a single line to multiple line for every 5 records but retain the first field using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with following pattern:

```
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|p6|p7 
SUB2|p1|p2
```

Now, the output required is:

```
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5  
SUB1|p6|p7  
SUB2|p1|p2
```

---

The rule is first field (`SUB1`, `SUB2` and so on) is an identifier for rest of the fields(`p1`,`p2`,`p3`,`p4`,`p5` and so on). After every 5 occurences of `p` it has to go to a new line but, along with the identifier field SUB. If the occurence of `p` is less than 5, it has to stay in the same line.

I have tried with:

```
awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i%6?"|":"\n""|")}}'
```

It can jump to a new line after 6 lines; but cannot retain the `SUB` in new line.

Comment: Why `SUB2|x1|x2` changed to `SUB2|p1|p2` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj. Sorry it's a mistake while framing the question. I have edited it the right way now.

Comment: try `awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i%6?"|":"\n"$1"|")}}' f` but it's a partial answer.

Comment: What should happen if 'p' appears more than five times in two or more consecutive lines? Do you want the first SUB or the second?

Comment: the real scenario is like: SUB1 (subscriber) has few products(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7). ALso, SUB2, SUB3 any amount of subscriber's can also have same products; thats why i had to mention "SUB" is an indentifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",(i%5==2?(i>2?RS:"")$1:"")FS,$i; print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^|]*)(\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*)\|(.*)$/\1\2\n\1|\3/g' file
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6|p7 
SUB2|p1|p2
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|p6|p7 
SUB2|p1|p2
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|p6
$ sed -r 's/^([^|]*)(\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*)\|(.*)$/\1\2\n\1|\3/g' file
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6|p7 
SUB2|p1|p2
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works like a champ. Is there any workaround that we could do it using awk?.

Comment: @Unihedron I do agree that you always should accept an answer, if there is an good one. But you should always wait some hour, someone may post a better answer.

Comment: @Jotne It was an auto-comment. That aside, I agree with your stance.

Comment: You probably need a loop in that `sed`. Won't work if there is more data in multiples of 5.

Comment: This could be shortened a bit: `gsed -r 's/^([^|]*)(\|[^|]*){5}/&\n\1/' file`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a alternate solution using `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", $F[0], splice @F, 1, 5 while @F>1' file
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6|p7|p8|p9|p10
SUB1|p11
SUB2|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB2|p6
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6|p7
```

#### Explanation:

- `-F'\|'`: Set the input field separator to `|`.
- `-l`: Chomps the newline and places it back during print.
- `-a`: Populates an array `@F` based on the input field separator.
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>) { .. }` loop to process each line.
- `-e`: Executes the code block that follows it.
- `print join "|", $F[0], splice @F, 1, 5 while @F>1`: Prints the first field and the next five fields from the array joined together with a `|` while reducing the array at the same time (using splice). We continue to do this until our array contains just the first element left in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
cat file
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|p6|p7
SUB2|p1|p2
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|p6
```

```
awk -F\| '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s|%s",(i%5==2?RS$1:""),$i} END {print ""}' file

SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6|p7
SUB2|p1|p2
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6
```

If a blank line at start is a problem then use this:

```
awk -F\| '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s|%s",(i%5==2?(NR==1&&i==2?"":RS)$1:""),$i} END {print ""}' file
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6|p7
SUB2|p1|p2
SUB1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
SUB1|p6
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I was just to post a fix for that.